# Android, set WRAP_CONTENT layout parameter of ImageView by code not working

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

This doesn't works as expected:

```
imageView = ImageView(context)
imageView.adjustViewBounds = true
imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
imageView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
```

The imageView is added to a TableRow layout (which is added to a Table).

Full function:

```
fun loadTable(data: List<ListItem>) = lifecycleScope.launch {

    val rowParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    val table = binding.table
    val context = table.context

    for (i in data.indices) {     
            val rowIndex = i / TABLE_COLUMNS

            val row: TableRow = if (table.childCount <= rowIndex) {
                val r = TableRow(context)
                r.layoutParams = rowParams
                binding.table.addView(r)
                table.layoutParams.width = myBitmap.width * TABLE_COLUMNS
                r
            } else {
                table[rowIndex] as TableRow
            }

            imageView = ImageView(context)
            imageView.adjustViewBounds = true
            imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
            imageView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)

            row.addView(imageView)      
    }
}
```

Expected result: the `imageView` display the image and has the same size.

Actual result: the `imageView` has a zero-size and image is not displayed.

With the layout inspector I can see that the attributes are correct, but the size of the `imageView` remains 0.0.

If I set the same attribute at design time, the `imageView` is displayed correctly.

Comment: Could you try load the bitmap asynchronously?

Comment: Bitmap is loaded from Room database in io-dispatched coroutine, do you means this?

Comment: What is the _ViewGroup_ - LinearLayout? ConstraintLayout? How is the image view added?

Comment: The imageView is added to a TableRow layout (wich is added to a Table).

Comment: Show all the code that builds the layout and any XML that you use.

Comment: Sample code added.

Comment: Try this: Each TableRow needs its own set of LayoutParams - you are sharing one set across all rows. In addition, the LayoutParams for a view are the LayoutParams for its ViewGroup - here it is TableLayout.LayoutParams and not TableRow.LayoutParams for a TableRow. The LayoutParams for the ImageView should be TableRow.LayoutParams. See if that is of any help.